# How to debug and understand SWF

Tags: flash, decompiling, decompiler

I have a SWF-file (without the source), and I need to understand exactly what goes on under the hood. The SWF-file is started with URL-parameters (flashvars) and produces produces some output. I need to figure out what logic is added to the input, to produce the output.

I have decompiled the source using JPEXS Flash Decompiler, but I have some difficulties:

1. I can't figure out what line in the code that's the entry point.
       What's the first file/method to be executed? There are A LOT of
       files...
2. How can i start the SWF-file in debug-mode with
           URL-parameters (flashvars)? In JPEXS it seem to be possible to start
           without parameters.
3. Is there a better tool for figuring out what
           the code does? If I could easyly rename classes and methods after I
           figure out what they to - things would be easier. The methods are
           called things like $3, and {/¤!.
4. What software would be best
           suited if I wanted to make changes to the SWF?

Comment: Now that we are in 2021 and Flash is over, I think this question might be of some interest to people who want to play their favourite games in the flash content projector but for some reason they are not working but hopefully they know programming and decide to decompile the game and fix it themselves. I don't know if comments bump questions, but if they don't, maybe give us an edit telling us if you made any progress with this since 2016 :))

Comment: Unfortunately, I have made zero progress since 2016.